# Using for loops to count by two

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am attempting to create a function which uses a for loop to add 2 to a starting number n times.

Assigned task:  "Create a function called  countingByTwo that takes in a number as an argument, and then uses that number to dictate how many times the computer will count by two. Your function should run a for loop and should loop as many times as the number argument, and should do the following:

- For each loop, add two to the startingNum variable.
- For each loop, log the value of startingNum to the developer console.
- After all the loops (but still in the function), return startingNum."

My code so far (lines 1 and 2 given):

```js
var startingNum = 10;
// Create a function that uses the above variable to count by twos.
var num1;

function countingByTwo(num1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
    startingNum += 2;
    console.log(startingNum);
  }
  return startingNum;
}

countingByTwo(4)
```

Comment: You don't need to declare num1, it's already being used as a parameter. Also not sure what your question is, since it works.

Comment: What is the actual question here? What goes wrong? I mean the code seems to work as expected ..?

Comment: Congratulations, this is a nice solution to your homework :) oh and welcome to SO :)

Comment: **@Drew**, your code looks fine. Add what you'll pass and what you'll get. It will help to have proper understanding about your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I belive this is what you need ?

```js
var startingNum = 10;
// Create a function that uses the above variable to count by twos.

function countingByTwo(num1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
    startingNum += 2;
    console.log(startingNum);
  }
  return startingNum;
}

console.log(countingByTwo(startingNum))
```

Comment: I suppose I just needed to call the function... thought something else was going on.  Sorry for the pain folks. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var startingNum = 10;
// Create a function that uses the above variable to count by two n times.

function countingByTwo(num) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    startingNum += 2;
    console.log(startingNum);
  }
  return startingNum;
}

countingByTwo(4) // 18
```

num does not need to be initialized, it is a parameter for countingByTwo. Code otherwise works as expected and should pass tests assuming functions and variables are named correctly.